# Javascript-Create Flash player

Tags: php, flash, flashvars

I've got the following server-side videoclip variable: `$fileName = "bin-debug/Video Source/Black Eyed Peas - The Time.flv";` I'm using the following Javascript to Create the Player with this videoclip(I'm using the Flex Video component)

```
function createPlayer(videoSource){
    document.writeln("<div id=\"player\">");
    document.writeln("<object width=\"489\" height=\"414\" FlashVars=\""+videoSource+"\">");
    document.writeln("<param name=\"player\" value=\"bin-debug/FlexPlayer.swf\">");
    document.writeln("<embed src=\"bin-debug/FlexPlayer.swf\" name=\"player\" width=\"489\" height=\"414\" FlashVars=\""+videoSource+"\">");
    document.writeln("</embed>");
    document.writeln("</object>");
    document.writeln("</div>");               
}
```

The function call is like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var videoSource = "<?php echo $fileName; ?>";
    createPlayer(videoSource);
</script>
```

For some reason the Player isn't playing different videos. Maybe the problem is in the MXML where videoSourcew tag is specified? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this

```
document.writeln("<param name=FlashVars value="+videoSource+">");
```

?

**EDIT**

Then you have define the FlashVars param but it's not called in the embed

Add this in the embed after height=\"414\"

```
FlashVars=\""+videoSource+"\"
```

for this result

```
document.writeln("<embed src=\"bin-debug/FlexPlayer.swf\" name=\"player\" width=\"489\" height=\"414\" FlashVars=\""+videoSource+"\">");
```

Comment: still not't playing different video

Comment: After running Google Chrome Inspect Element I saw that the param tag is looking like this: <param name="FlashVars" value="bin-debug/Video" source... The slashes won't close where they have to. Maybe there is need to use %20 instead of space?

Comment: I edited the code above after Inspect element it looks right but the video in the player isn't changing